# How to replace an integer with a different class when it is assigned

Tags: python

I have a class called newInteger, and a variable called num, but I would like num to be a newInteger() instead of an int(). Code below.

```
class newInteger(int):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

num = 10
```

I want the line `num = 10` to act as if it is `num = newInteger(10)`. Thanks to anyone who can help me with this.

Comment: You can do `num = newInteger(10)`. `num` becomes the class instance. Can you explain what you are expecting?

Comment: Can you explain the use case? It could be easier to answer with an example use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a small thread parallel to your main program that replaces all created integers to `newInteger`:

```
import threading
import time

class newInteger(int):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return "newInteger " + str(self.value)

def replace_int():
    while True:
        g = list(globals().items())
        for n, v in g:
            if type(v) == int:
                globals()[n] = newInteger(v)

threading.Thread(target=replace_int, daemon=True).start()
num = 10
time.sleep(1)
print(num)
```

But this is unpythonic and will be realy hard to debug. You should just use a explicit conversion [like @johnashu proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50305798/8472976)

Comment: Thanks heaps for this answer, it really helped.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you mean but if youassign the class to a variabl.  then it will be an instance of that class..

example:

```
class newInteger(int):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

num = 10

if num == 10:
    num = newInteger(10)
```

prints:
    `hello`

Comment: That's not quite it, but thanks anyway for trying. To put it basically, I wanted the line num = newInteger(10) to be run when I wrote num = 10.

Comment: Megalng's answer is correct. Thanks for helping though.